# How to get text from image using pytesseract in images

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, ocr, python-tesseract

I need to use pytesseract to extract text from this picture. This is possible?
ex.images:

[image]

[image]

[image: "[3]: "]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

im = Image.open("4.jpg") # the second one 
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
im.save('4temp.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('4temp.jpg'))
print(text)
```

Decoded text:

> 1 - EN
> 2- f-ybizc
> 3- CALE NGS
> 4- [BLANK]

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to bypass a CAPTCHA and therefore are probably breaking the terms of service for the resource you are trying to access. See if you can find a better way. These images are purposely hard for a computer to read.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answer! Yeah its a CAPTCHA, but i not want use it for evil purposes. We have a page with offers that every 10 ads require entering a captcha in order to refresh the advertisement. Captcha is send by POST. After enter the site we have captchaid. That Captcha generate by javascript and it is deleted from server after 1min.   I think it is a best method but idk ;/